# Conversion of a number from binary to decimal Most significant bits (MSB) causing undesireable result

Tags: java, recursion

In main method when I'm trying to pass a binary number as `Integer` the most significant bit when `1` gives the desired result. But when I change it to `0` it gives unexpected results. 
As a remedy, I have to convert `string` to `integer` and then pass it.

```
public class BinaryToDecimal {


   static int BinaryNum(int n, int p){
        if(n==0){
            return 0;
        }
        else{
            return (int)((n%10)*(Math.pow(2, p))+BinaryNum(n/10,p+1));
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(BinaryNum(Integer.parseInt("001010"), 0));
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, I'd _expect_ that changing a bit your binary number will change the result, so I'm afraid I don't understand the problem.  Could you offer some examples of particular inputs along with both expected and actual results?

Comment: You can't use a binary return value for a decimal representation. At best your function will return the same value as the input. You need a return type with a different radix you can control, such as `String`, or indeed `BigDecimal`.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use the built-in [Integer#parseInt(s, radix)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String,%20int)) method:

```
Integer.parseInt("001010", 2)
```

`2` is the radix (base) for the number here telling that it's a binary (base-2) number. It will automatically convert `001010` binary number to `10` decimal value.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this recursively on your own you can do it this way.

```
static int BinaryNum(String n, int p) {
    if (n.length() == 1) {
        return (int) (Integer.parseInt(n) * Math.pow(2, p));
    } else {
        return (int) ((n.charAt(n.length() - 1) - 48) * Math.pow(2, p)) + BinaryNum(n.substring(0, n.length() - 1), p + 1);
    }
}

  public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(BinaryNum("101010", 0));
    }
```